# Passing through through segue / segmented control

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, swift2, segue

I want to pass data from my `UISettingsViewController` to my `UIViewController`(Main view).

what I was trying to do is that when I set a default tip rate in the `UISettingsViewController` the values and the tip rate in the `UIViewController` change, for example if I set the default tip rate to 10% it changes in the main view controller and sets as default when I open the app.

I hope this is a clear explanation, I'm from other country that doesn't talks English.

Please see the images that I leave for have a better view of what I'm trying to do, I Stitch the images [The View MainStoryBoard (user interface)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71paq.png)[code of Two Views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KprMK.jpg)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
// Inputs
@IBOutlet weak var amountTextField: UITextField!
//Labels
@IBOutlet weak var TipPercentageLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var numberOfPersonLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var tipAmountLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var totalBillLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var billPerPersonLabel: UILabel!
//Slider & Stepper
@IBOutlet weak var tipSlider: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var personsStepper: UIStepper!
//Variables
var tipPercentage:Double = 0.20
var numberOfPerson:Int = 1
let numberFormatter:NSNumberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    tipAmountLabel.text = "$0.00"
    totalBillLabel.text = "Bill Total"
    billPerPersonLabel.text = "$0.00"
    TipPercentageLabel.text =  "20.0%"
    numberOfPersonLabel.text = "1"
    self.amountTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
func setupContainer() {


    tipSlider.minimumValue = 0
    tipSlider.maximumValue = 100
    tipSlider.value = 20
    tipSlider.addTarget(self, action: "sliderTipChanged:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

    personsStepper.minimumValue = 1
    personsStepper.maximumValue = 30
    personsStepper.value = 1
    personsStepper.addTarget(self, action: "sliderPersonChanged:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

    amountTextField.text = ""

    refreshCalculation()

}

@IBAction func OnEditingFieldBill(sender: AnyObject) {

    refreshCalculation()
}

func refreshCalculation() {

    numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle
    if let amount = numberFormatter.numberFromString(amountTextField.text!) as? Double {

        let tipAmount = amount * tipPercentage
        let totalBill = amount + tipAmount
        let billPerPerson = totalBill / Double(numberOfPerson)
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
        tipAmountLabel.text = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(tipAmount)
        totalBillLabel.text = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(totalBill)
        billPerPersonLabel.text = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(billPerPerson)

    } else {

        tipAmountLabel.text = "-"
        totalBillLabel.text = "-"
        billPerPersonLabel.text = "-"
    }

    numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.PercentStyle
    numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 1
    numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1
    TipPercentageLabel.text = self.numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(tipPercentage)

   numberOfPersonLabel.text = "\(numberOfPerson)"

} 

@IBAction func sliderTipChanged(sender: UISlider) {

    tipPercentage = Double(round(tipSlider.value)) / 100
    refreshCalculation()
}


@IBAction func StepperPersonChanged(sender: UIStepper) {
    numberOfPerson = Int(round(personsStepper.value))
    refreshCalculation()
}
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var DestViewController : SettingsViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SettingsViewController
    DestViewController =

   }
}
```

Where says `DestViewController =` in the last line , is where I don't know what to do and if is good or not

**second view controller**

```
import UIKit

class SettingsViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var tipControl: UISegmentedControl!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@IBAction func DefaultRate(sender: AnyObject) {
    var tipRate = [5, 10, 15, 2, 25, 30]
    var tipRates = tipRate[tipControl.selectedSegmentIndex]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, when you change the default rate on the settings you want that to have an immediate effect on the main view. Therefore I would suggest you create a protocol in the settings and add a weak delegate property that conforms to this protocol (which you would set as the mainViewController). Then when the rate has changed in the settings trigger the call on the delegate that would in turn cause the refreshCalculation in the mainViewController. Using the delegate pattern makes the intent and the relationship between the 2 very clear and type safe but also prevents retain cycles between the 2 view controllers. In addition, you want the default to be set when the mainViewController loads so would also need to save the rate in NSUserDefaults when it is changed. And read it from the NSUserDefaults in the initialisation of the main view with a backup of 0.20.

```
protocol SettingsDelegate {
  func tipPercentageChanged(newValue : Double)
}

class SettingsVC : UIViewController {
  var destName : String!
  var delegate : SettingsDelegate?

  @IBAction func segmentedValueChanged(sender : UISegmentedControl){

    var tipRates = [0.05, 0.10, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.30]
    let tipRate = tipRates[sender.selectedSegmentIndex]

    delegate?.tipPercentageChanged(tipRate)

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setDouble(tipRate, forKey: "DefaultTipRate")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
  }
}

class MainVC : UIViewController, SettingsDelegate {

  var tipPercentage : Double = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().doubleForKey("DefaultTipRate") ?? 0.20

  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let settingsVC = segue.destinationViewController as? SettingsVC{
      settingsVC.delegate = self
    }
  }

  func tipPercentageChanged(newValue: Double) {
    tipPercentage = newValue
    refreshCalculation()
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks  Lot, but here is what I get [link] (http://imgur.com/yb54FnW) [link] (http://imgur.com/yoSlssT)

Comment: The example I gave above includes defining a protocol called SettingsDelegate. The purpose of that is to define a method that a conforming class ( in this example MainVC) would implement. This is a very common in iOS and always has been. To remove this error implement ```func tipPercentageChanged(newValue: Double) {
    tipPercentage = newValue
    refreshCalculation()
  }```

Comment: for the second issue. You need to set ````self```` as the delegate on the settingsViewController not newValue. This is so when the delegate call is made in comes to the right place. Also it's good practice to name instances with lower case names and classes with upper case for readability. Maybe have a bit of a search for using the delegate pattern in iOS. To make sue you fully understand this pattern. It will come up often.

Comment: thanks Dallas Johnson, I have some Issues now I will appreciate your help

Comment: When I begin type the amount "tipPercentage" goes "0.0" and the I select a default tipRate and when I go back to the main view is in 15% then I begin type an amount and do the same

Answer (score 0):

The way to pass data between controllers is for the controller you want to give the data to (in this case the View Controller) to have a public property that can be set in the segue source controller (in this case the Settings View Controller).

I see that that your View Controller has a property called `tipPercentage`, so I'm assuming that this is the value you want to set. I also see that you have two segues, one from the View Controller to the Settings View Controller and back. Note that it is important to set the segue identifiers in the storyboard, even if you only have one segue it keeps your code clean, maintainable and bug free. If you had more than one segue, the identifier would be a must.

To set the identifiers, go into your Storyboard, click on the segues themselves, and in the right pane give them an identifier. for the purpose of this code I'll call the first segue **"showSettings"** and the second **"goBackToViewController"**.

The way you do prepare for segue is a little different than what you did. The few lines you wrote at the end of ViewController should read:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender:AnyObject?) {
    if let id = segue.identifier { //identifier could be nil
       if id == "showSettings" {
           if let swv = segue.destination.destinationViewController as? SettingsViewController {
               //Do any preparation here 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now for the segue you're actually interested in, we need to prepare a little bit. First of all, you declared `tipRates` in a function, so it will never be accessible from prepareFoeSegue:. Instead at the top of the class declare the variable:

```
var tipRates:Double?
```

and change default rate like so:

```
@IBAction func DefaultRate(sender: AnyObject) {
    var tipRate = [5, 10, 15, 2, 25, 30]
    tipRates = Double(tipRate[tipControl.selectedSegmentIndex]) //We cast because tipRates is a double but tipRate an [Int]
}
```

Now that we can access the variable within the class, we can segue happily. Put the following code in your SettingsViewController:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender:AnyObject?) {
    if let id = segue.identifier { //identifier could be nil
       if id == "goBackToViewController" {
           if let vc = segue.destination.destinationViewController as? ViewController {
                if let tip = tipRates {
                    vc.tipPercentage = tip/100 //We want the percentage
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Et voila! Your ViewController has gotten the information. Lastly, do notice that it's bad form to explicitly mention type when the compiler can figure it out. For example, 
`var tipPercentage:Double = 0.20`
should really be 
`var tipPercentage = 0.20`

when the compiler knows it's a double just by looking at the value. Also, consider embedding the app in a UINavigationController for ease of navigation.

Comment: Thanks,  I do all as you said, and it runs but when I try changing the default tip rate It doesnt do anything in the ViewCcontroller, it just clear just like I just restart the app. Also I didnt set any Identifier , is that ok?

Comment: If you copy pasted the code, then yes, since it checks for the identifier. And it's always good practice to add identifiers. Put breakpoints in the prepareForSegue: method to make sure everything is going smoothly